# How to get treeview with collapse functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, treeview, ancestry

I rendered the treeview using 'ancestry' gem, it works fine. How to get the tree collapse/expand functionality like jquery-treeview?

Comment: Some offtop. On our project we are using nested_sets for tree representation. https://github.com/the-teacher/the_sortable_tree saves us

Comment: In the_sortable_tree gem expand/collapse animation is under development. I also tried this gem and getting only the nested view without collapse/expand functionality.

Comment: I sure hope someone answers this !!!  I'd like to know how.

Comment: I also hope someone answers this! I also would like to know how too!

Comment: just use any js plugin, like the one that twitter bootstrap has i.e